# How to create a "spinning" effect of a column of number images

Tags: ios

I am using Xcode 6 and coding in Swift. I am relatively new to Swift but have programming experience in C.

I am creating a column of random numbers which I display by programmatically creating image views with the appropriate number image.
My logic is as follows:

1. User presses a "spin" button
2. A function is called which creates a column of random numbers (ex: say 5 numbers) and displays the appropriate number image for each.
3. Instead of just generating my 5 numbers, displaying them and leaving the function, I put this in a loop that will process 100 times.
4. The purpose of the loop is to create a "spinning" effect.

This is where my problem arises. I do not get a spinning effect, instead I simply see the last 5 generated numbers that were displayed.

As best as I can tell with my limited understanding of when things occur, it seems as though the images don't actually update until the function (which was called by  the user tapping a button) completes and returns.

Is this true?

If so how can I create my "spinning" effect?

How can I get the numbers to display at the time I generate and assign my number image?

This is the first time I've used this forum (as far as asking a question) and apologize in advance for anything I've done wrong when laying out my question.

Thank you - Ed